# Bokeh 0.12.4 to 0.12.5 -- Twisted Server proxying to the Bokeh Server fails

Tags: python, websocket, twisted, bokeh

I use a twisted python server for hosting an overview page that links to apps running on a bokeh server. The twisted server proxies incoming requests (something like `<globalip>:80`) to the bokeh server (on port `5006`).

I decided to use the twisted server, since I wanted to be able to run the whole system just with anaconda python. With bokeh 0.12.4 this solution worked well.

I hope the example below illustrates the problem with my server setup that occours on bokeh version 0.12.5. Currently I suspect that something with websockets and the twisted server is going wrong, but since I am quite inexperienced with websockets I have no clue where to start.

### Minmal Example

#### Bokeh application

The bokeh server hosts the sliders app from https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/sliders.py on `localhost:5006`.

- saved in Sliders/main.py
- running with `bokeh serve Sliders --port 5006 --host localhost:5006 --allow-websocket-origin=127.0.0.1:8080` (I basically came up with this combination of `--host` and `--allow-websocket-origin` by trial and error; this works under bokeh 0.12.4)
- (simply running the app without the server works perfectly fine `bokeh serve --show Sliders`

#### Twisted server

The Twisted server hosts a website on `127.0.0.1:8080` with a link to `127.0.0.1:8080/apps/Sliders`. If the user calls this link, the server proxies to the bokeh server app on `localhost:5006\Sliders`.

- running with python twisted_server.py

*twisted_server.py*

```
from twisted.internet import reactor  
from twisted.web import proxy, server  
from twisted.web.static import File

resource = File('./www/')  
resource.putChild('apps',proxy.ReverseProxyResource('localhost', 5006, ''))  
site = server.Site(resource)  
reactor.listenTCP(8080, site)  
reactor.run()
```

*www/index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
  <title>Sliders</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<p>
<a target="_blank" href="apps/Sliders">Sliders</a>
```

#### running under Bokeh 0.12.4

`conda install bokeh=0.12.4`

With the configuration above everything runs fine. I can open `127.0.0.1:8080` in the browser, click on the link to the Sliders app and the app is opened and can be interacted with.

#### running under Bokeh 0.12.5

`conda install bokeh=0.12.5`

The configuration above allows me to open `127.0.0.1:8080`. Clicking on the link to the Sliders app only results in a blank page. The output of the bokeh server shell is given below.

Since the `--host` parameter has been deprecated in bokeh 0.12.5, I already tried various argument combinations in `--allow-websocket-origin` that didn't work either.

If anybody can help me decrypt the error message `GET 400 ...` that would be greatly appreciated.

*Bokeh Server Output*

```
C:\Users\Benjamin\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\bokeh\command\subcommands\serve.py:325: UserWarning: The --host parameter is deprecated because it is no longer needed. It will be removed and trigger an error in a future release. Values set now will be copied to --allow-websocket-origin. Depending on your use case, you may need to set current --host values for 'allow_websocket_origin' instead.
"The --host parameter is deprecated because it is no longer needed. "
2017-04-20 12:18:00,375 Starting Bokeh server version 0.12.5
2017-04-20 12:18:00,454 Starting Bokeh server on port 5006 with applications at paths ['/Sliders']
2017-04-20 12:18:00,454 Starting Bokeh server with process id: 2308
2017-04-20 12:18:25,055 200 GET /Sliders (127.0.0.1) 543.00ms
2017-04-20 12:18:25,915 400 GET /Sliders/ws?bokeh-protocol-version=1.0&bokeh-session-id=FICIeGnPQLGK7363ORLcpTPMVBCiPffpOgGx2qdy5AdM (127.0.0.1) 0.00ms
```

Comment: I tried the approach mentioned by @bigreddot , but unfortunately this did not help.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a duplicate of:

[bokeh serve running but can't access with browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43451585/bokeh-serve-running-but-cant-access-with-browser/43485261#43485261)

In which case you need to downgrade from the recently released Tornado 4.5 or upgrade to a newer Bokeh version that has the fix for the incompatibility.

Comment: I just tried this approach, but did not get it working. Still the same errors.