# Bokeh serve examples not running (were before) as web browser hangs

Tags: python, tornado, jupyter, bokeh

I'm running in Firefox on Ubuntu 14.04 (Anaconda3... 32-bit version) and on another machine 16.04 LTS (Anacond3... 64-bit version) and saw the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43451585/bokeh-serve-running-but-cant-access-with-browser) and followed the install instructions but this did not fix on either machine (my Tornado version is 4.4.2).

I am trying example under "Connecting with bokeh.client" [here](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html)

On my 16.04 machine I had the *bokeh serve* examples running from both my jupyter notebook (after typing in a terminal: *bokeh serve*) and in a terminal (by typing: *bokeh serve --show my_bokeh_example.py*  <-- which is from the code immediately under the bokeh.client link above), but updated numpy and pandas, now they don't work.

...So I figure I'd install Anaconda on my 14.04 machine and it works in the jupyter notebook (after typing in a terminal: *bokeh serve*) but doesn't work from the terminal command (*bokeh serve --show my_bokeh_example.py*)

On my 16.04 machine I've tried uninstalling/re-installing bokeh and restarted (several times) but that didn't work.  When it did work, as I ran it several times, it would show the changing wiggly sine graph (as it should look), then other times it would show one frozen, with one moving graph) and now does nothing but open a new tab and do nothing.

In the console I see:

```
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘gray’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  bokeh.min.css:1:34728
Expected color but found ‘default’.  Error in parsing value for ‘color’.  Declaration dropped.  bokeh.min.css:1:53023
Selector expected.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.  bokeh.min.css:1:53406
Unexpected end of file while searching for closing } of invalid rule set.  bokeh.min.css:2
Expected end of value but found ‘\9 ’.  Error in parsing value for ‘margin-top’.  Declaration dropped.  bokeh-widgets.min.css:157:458
Expected color but found ‘auto’.  Expected color but found ‘-webkit-focus-ring-color’.  Expected end of value but found ‘-webkit-focus-ring-color’.  Error in parsing value for ‘outline’.  Declaration dropped.  bokeh-widgets.min.css:157:775
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-ms-input-placeholder’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.  bokeh-widgets.min.css:157:1378
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-webkit-input-placeholder’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.  bokeh-widgets.min.css:157:1441
Unknown property ‘user-select’.  Declaration dropped.  bokeh-widgets.min.css:157:8610
Expected color but found ‘auto’.  Expected color but found ‘-webkit-focus-ring-color’.  Expected end of value but found ‘-webkit-focus-ring-color’.  Error in parsing value for ‘outline’.  Declaration dropped.  bokeh-widgets.min.css:157:8746
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  bokeh-widgets.min.css:157:9232
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘progid’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  bokeh-widgets.min.css:157:20423
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  bokeh-widgets.min.css:157:36209
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  bokeh-widgets.min.css:157:47537
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  bokeh-widgets.min.css:157:56285
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  bokeh-widgets.min.css:157:56477
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  bokeh-widgets.min.css:157:56567
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  bokeh-widgets.min.css:157:69501
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  bokeh-widgets.min.css:157:69678
Unknown property ‘-moz-box-shadow’.  Declaration dropped.  bokeh-widgets.min.css:157:75577
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-ms-input-placeholder’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.  bokeh-widgets.min.css:157:143534
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-webkit-input-placeholder’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.  bokeh-widgets.min.css:157:143599
Selector expected.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.  bokeh-widgets.min.css:157:145013
Unexpected end of file while searching for closing } of invalid rule set.  bokeh-widgets.min.css:158
[bokeh] setting log level to: 'info'  bokeh.min.js:4:23237
[bokeh] Websocket connection 0 is now open  bokeh.min.js:1:7316
Bokeh items were rendered successfull  bokeh.min.js:24:26320
```

Is there something in iptables (I am able to use localhost and/or 127.0.0.1 and have a very basic /etc/hosts file) or some other network thingy that would be blocking this?

Thanks in advance!

cd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bokeh.client` examples are specifically *not* run like `bokeh serve --show myapp.py`. They are run in two steps, per the instructions on that page:

```
bokeh serve # no additional arguments
```

then separately

```
python client_app.py
```

If `client_app.py` calls `session.show(...)` as the example in the docs does, then a browser should open automatically to the correct URL (which is more complicated and has the session ID as part of it).

However, I would not recommend using `bokeh.client` It is mostly useful as a testing tool. Instead, create "real Bokeh apps" follwing the instruction and examples in [Building Bokeh Applications](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#building-bokeh-applications). Those are the kind of applications that are run with `bokeh serve myapp.py`